# VS Code ON ubuntu 16.04 not showing the right launcher icon after installation

Tags: 16.04, text-editor

After installing VS Code i'm getting a default icon  not that one that comes with vs code

How can i get it look like these ?

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Based on VS Code developers on github we can solve this by changing the path to the right icon like so:

```
sudo nano /usr/share/applications/code.desktop
```

And change the Icon link to :

```
Icon=/usr/share/pixmaps/code.png
```

It should Look like so:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Visual Studio Code
Comment=Code Editing. Redefined.
GenericName=Text Editor
Exec=/usr/share/code/code --unity-launch %U
Icon=/usr/share/pixmaps/code.png
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
StartupWMClass=Code
Categories=Utility;TextEditor;Development;IDE;
MimeType=text/plain;inode/directory;
Actions=new-window;
Keywords=vscode;

X-Desktop-File-Install-Version=0.22

[Desktop Action new-window]
Name=New Window
Name[de]=Neues Fenster
```

Comment: `Icon=code` was how mine was set by default. Changed it to the path you specified and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: I have installed VS Code via Snap on Ubuntu Budgie 18.04 and I have this code.png graphic file missing. Where I could download the original?

Comment: @Marecky: I had the same problem, but you should find a copy in `/usr/share/code/resources/app/resources/linux`. Open Terminal, navigate to that folder and try this command: `sudo cp code.png /usr/share/pixmaps/code.png`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no information about HOW did you install your software. In Ubuntu there are several ways to install packages, some of them may be harder, some easier. I recommend reading this tutorial first:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux

Im pretty sure that these steps will lead you to succes installation with your icons working fine.

PS: To uninstall your current version you can use

sudo apt-get purge code

Just in case you don't know.

Comment: Hi there the problem is not because of the installation i followed vs code installation guide besides i have seen some people reporting the same problem on github   but now i solved it  :) thanks for feedback

Comment: You're  welcome bro, glad to hear you've fixed what was broken :)
Many ppl tend to install packages wrong way, so I started simply. Plus, I had no problem with icons installing it this way, so my answer was based on my experience.

Answer (score 0):

Add this path to the icon:

```
/snap/code/current/meta/gui/com.visualstudio.code.png
```